# how can I change the web server's identity into mine?

Tags: linux, linux-networking, arch-linux

Can the web server execute a command in my Linux environment, and the Linux environment treat it as a request coming from me not from the server?

In other words, how can I change the web server's identity into mine?

Comment: This sounds like a way to create a **huge** security hole. If you need the webserver to do [something] then you should give it the correct permissions to do so.

Answer (score 2):

You could have the webserver run a script which calls a properly configured `sudo` to execute commands as another user.

Alternatively, if you're using Apache then you could use [mod_suexec](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_suexec.html), which allows you to run commands as a different user straight from the webserver.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, but can you give me more detail, I'm using the su command like this:echo password | su -c mycommand -s /bin/sh mchentou, but even-thought it does not work, am I missing something? thanks again

Comment: You can't pipe the password into `su` like that.  If you want to do it like that, edit the `sudo` configuration file (with `visudo`) and add a rule for your webserver to be able to run your command as the appropriate user.  Then you can do `sudo -u mchentou mycommand`.  However, it would be more secure to use something like `mod_suexec` if you can.